# Click event not working on dynamically added button or Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, onclick, controls

I am using following code in C# to add a Button

```
Button TextLabel = new Button(); //local variable
TextLabel.Location = new Point(0, 0);
TextLabel.Visible = true;
TextLabel.Enabled = true;
TextLabel.AutoSize = true;
TextLabel.Click += click;
this.Controls.Add(TextLabel);
```

And its click handler is

```
protected void click(object o, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Though the Button is visible and responding to mouse hover, but nothing is happening on its click. What could be wrong or missing?
If I write this same code in an independent project, it works!!!!! Strange. but why????

Form Properties: (if required)
1. Show in taskbar: false
2. Borderless
3. 50% Opaque

Comment: Where do you put this code? Is it in constructor, OnLoad section?

Comment: Thanks all, I got my answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I realised that just registering click event for a control will not make any event to work unless its parent (in my case its form) on which that control is still active.

Parent control will receive event notification earlier than its child controls. This is a simple and obvious observation, but if not paid attention will make undesirable effects.

That's the mistake I did, I made another form active on my form activated event, hence any control in it didn't received events like mouse clicks.

Talking of 'hover effects are working', then yes, even if a form is inactive, hover works.

So I just removed the line of code that made another form active and everything is working fine now.

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (form2!=null) form2.BringToFront(); //commented this
}
```